# How to create a space from commandline in Mac?

Tags: command-line, catalina, spaces

I want to be able to create a new space from the command-line so that I can quickly launch a set of applications in a particular space.

Would be preferable if I could directly create the space in a shell script.

That way the overall process would become easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "a new space"?

Comment: Do you mean a Desktop, as in Mission Control?

Comment: Yes, I mean a new Desktop, as in Mission Control.